# High server load with ngix+php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I successfully installed nging+php5-fpm. Everything works fine but on the same machine server load is higher than with Apache2+php.

With Apache2+php I was running 2 websites and average server load was 0.1...0.2...0.3 and at peaktimes about 0.8-0.9.

With nginx+php5 fpm I am running only one busy website (the same as with apache) but the load is higher - 0.3... 0.6... 0.7, and it's not a peaktime.

Is it possible to optimize something (php5-fpm or nginx)? Should I change some values in nginx.conf file like worker_processes (is set to 4 niow) or worker_connections (is set to 768 now)? Should I change anything in php5-fpm config. file? When I run top, I see that the most cpu consuming processes are php5-fpm.

My server details: AMD Opteron™ 3280 Octo-Core 8x 2.4 GHz 16 GB RAM

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing well, LA 0.7 is pretty low for 8-core processor.
You server should perform without slowdown until you have LA higher then number of cores.

Comment: yes, I know 0.7 is pretty low and not a problem yet. I wonder why the load is higher than with Apache+php. I installed nginx+php5-fpm because I have heard that it's faster and will reduce the load. But the load is even higher.

Comment: nginx+php5-fpm is not significantly faster or slower than apache+modphp. But it do consume much less memory per process.

Comment: so, changing settings in nginx.conf or php5-fpm config. files is senseless?

Comment: It's impossible to say something with information you have provided.